# How to analyze crash dump of EXE/DLL files which were protected by vmprotect

Tags: crash, dump

I am confused about how people analyze crash dump files generated by exe/dll files which were protected by VMProtect(3.0 or later). Even though I have the original exe/dll, the map file, and the pdb file, I can not find the original call stack or the crash point in the C++ source code. Does anyone know how to analyze these dump files? I'v got a huge amount of dump files to be handle...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "MiniDump Fixer" to fix minidump files:
https://vmpsoft.com/20111114/minidump-fixer/